# Likelihood of super man being a truly nasty person?

Tags: super-powers, psychology

Given that superman is, essentially, imbued with god-like power, in a world where (let's be honest) he could easily dispatch anyone with kryptonite, what is the likelihood that - eventually - he would become an evil person?

I'm not positing that he would have to arrive and inherit some behaviour like that depicted in Brightburn, though that's a great movie, but just a regular 'person' with god-like powers (ok, minus the ability to create matter from nothing, I suppose).

What would he likely become, as a person, according to current thinking in the field of psychology?

Comment: What is the worldbuilding problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm not, per se, but I'm interested in the repercussions of such progression in a person. Ultimately, I don't see this person being mid-way on the good/evil spectrum, but falling hard toward either end.

Comment: As a philosophical question, this goes back [at least as far as Plato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_Gyges).

Comment: @L.Dutch - Reinstate Monica Worldbuilding problem? For example, whether a "[Reckoners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reckoners)" world is a logical consequence of superpowers, or it's just an unlikely option.

Comment: I think that this is purely opinion.

Comment: @NomadMaker unfortunately, the entire field of psychology is opinion-based.

Comment: @Alexander Is that literally true or is there scientific method applied? Unfortunately, your statement implies, to the layman, that the field can't be trusted and that is not a convincing argument (whether it's one your making or not.)

Comment: @Matt W psychology is one of the "soft sciences", which means that the number of methods normally used in hard science (precise measurement, logical proof etc.) are not quite applicable there. With the rigorous "opinion-based" standard employed here at Worldbuilding SE, any psychology-based question is in danger of being closed.

Comment: Why? You just described Worldingbuild and Psychology both as opinion-based. Surely, if most people here are using it to build stories, there would necessarily be a large number of soft-science posts.

Comment: @Matt W Worldbuilding, in general, is not opinion-based. Psychology (imho) is. What I'm talking about is that Worldbuilding SE has a lower level of tolerance for soft-science questions than Psychology & Neuroscience SE.

Answer (score 5):

**Depends on when superhumans get their powers and what kind of guidance they receive**

Human morals are largely acquired from the society as part of child's upbringing. An individual may be naturally inclined to be more cruel or more emphatic, but most of the knowledge of right and wrong is taught as a child grows up.

This way it is critical that superhumans have plenty of chance to absorb as much human morale as possible before they grow to full power.

A child who has superpowers from early age would think of themselves as exceptional, any might think less of the other, regular people. Proper parenting and proper education (ex. "Xavier School for Gifted Youngsters") is exceptionally important if we want to end up with superheroes rather than supervillains.

If all that education fails (or was never present to begin with) there is a very high chance that superpowered child would grow up to be power-hungry and egoistic.

Answer (score 4):

Well as far as being a complete psychopath, those only make up about 1% of the population, so you have about a 1% chance. Of course, not being a psychopath does not equal good, and even "good people" do bad things on occasion.

Over all, I'd say the chances of getting an evil superhuman if powers are distributed randomly is quite a bit higher then what is portrayed in your average superhero movie, but  not nearly as much as what you see in *Brightburn* or *The Boys*.

I think a fair percentage of them will have good intentions (that doesn't mean that they won't do bad things), a percentage would have bad intentions, and the majority will just have selfish intent in deciding between doing good or bad based only on what options they thought best benefit then.

Comment: The Boys is a bad example, because *all* powers come from the drug V, usually directly, but sometimes indirectly like MM. What I'm trying to say is that most people with powers received it directly, and we never saw anybody with only small powers.

Comment: I think I was expecting answers based on the inherent ability of the individual being 'super', rather than them being 'distributed' - though it's an interesting take. I am, however, asking about what the natural effect of a complete set of Superman abilities would be if the individual were imbued from birth (making 'given' or 'inherited' a somewhat academic debate I realise.)

Comment: Even being a complete psychopath isn't sufficient: the average psychopath might not be bothered by the idea of killing people or doing other nasty things, it's just that it's not usually worth the effort :-)

Answer (score 2):

#### 1%

But there's a ~75% chance he's moral and selfless.

The superman story (as I recall it anyway) explains supermans morals as being given by his strong American rural morale upbringing, including (to my surprise) [faith in god](https://screenrant.com/superman-believe-god-comic-christian/) and other rural Illinois values. I tried to work out statistically his morals from his locale and I've got a Pro-Life [Evangelical](https://www.pewforum.org/religious-landscape-study/state/illinois/) who...  [votes democrat](https://www.270towin.com/states/Illinois). I'm not sure how helpful this is - I don't recall ever seeing Clark Kent in church in SmallVille.

There are a few studies that show that power doesn't corrupt, but it heightens pre-existing tendencies, sociopaths get more sociopathic, selfless people care about others more. [1](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/why-power-corrupts-37165345/) [2](https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/economy/power-doesnt-corrupt-it-just-exposes-who-leaders-really-are/2019/02/22/f5680116-3600-11e9-854a-7a14d7fec96a_story.html) [3](https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2013/07/how-power-corrupts-the-mind/277638/)

[1% of people are sociopaths](https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2018/mar/30/michael-mccaul/michael-mccaul-says-1-100-people-sociopath/) (we hope he's not one of these), but beyond that we need to work out what's the likely hood that he's selfish or selfless. There are studies showing people cheating more when nobodies watching and stuff like that (especially when they think there are zero consequences), but I think its most telling when people offer to lower their standing to advance their poorer neighbours.

People are generally pretty selfless when faced with choices which affect those around them - [Here 72% wishing to double unemployment benifits](https://anglicanfocus.org.au/2020/05/07/poll-shows-we-must-raise-the-rate-of-jobseeker-for-good/), [and 77% thinks its critical to do so, even if they pay more tax](https://news.gallup.com/opinion/polling-matters/258335/social-security-american-public-opinion.aspx).

If superman has standard human morality - there's a fairly good (~75%) chance he'll be a decent person. 1% chance he'll be horrible, and about 24% chance he's neutral.

Comment: It's worth noting that "studies" in areas like unemployment benefits are generally heavily pre-biased in one direction or another, but this is still a good answer.

Comment: In the comics Superman is mostly neutral on the subject of religion. His parents brought him up with a strong moral upbringing rather than a religious one.

Comment: Smallville is in Kansas, not Illinois.

Answer (score 2):

## 99%

Let's take a real example of someone who had ideals and came to power. At first, he studied to become a priest and joined a political party as a lowly member that wanted to better the lot of the larger population. He ended in the group around their leader and went through the worst. His party ended up overthrowing the oppressive conservative government for the better of the people. The clique he was part of managed to end the raging war but had to restructure a desolate country afterward, attempting to follow their ideals. After the death of the previous leader, he ended up clawing his way to be the leader's successor, going so far to have his fellow comrades of years killed. He became a dictator that allied with his mortal ideological enemy, then backstabbed him, allying with his former-ally-now-enemy's mortal ideological enemy who was just as well his own ideological mortal enemy. Anyone that was even remotely not following his ideas, he sent into prison camps and worked them to death. Yes, the guy I am talking about [Joseph Stalin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Stalin).

The world molds people and the more powerful they are and the loftier their ideals, the more the world makes them the worst they can be. It takes the special care of Ma and Pa Kent to make a do-gooder like Superman.

### Absolute power corrupts absolute.

Comment: They say Stalin was the original Man of Steel.

Comment: I think you mean 'absolutely' but I take your point. I didn't know that about Stalin, but I'm not a historian. Thanks for the education. However, the perspective I'm asking about is if that power were not simply by proxy but directly imbued. I do, however, agree entirely with your point about Ma and Pa Kent and think that would be the overriding factor (outside of a Brightburn situation.)

Comment: Actually there are accounts a people that knew him that say that Stalin was a psychopath from the when he was a child.